# How to print x:include hierarchy

Tags: xml, xsd, xslt-1.0, libxml2

I have about 500 xml documents, each of them about 20000 lines. They  include eachother, either fully or parts (specified by xpointer)

I have to figure out, how they are related.
Is it possible to resolve (and print) the include hierarchy of a given file after having invoked xinclude? Is the invoke history somewhere stored in the resulting dom abd accessible from a stylesheet?

For sample1.xml I need this information:

```
sample1.xml
    |- sample2.xml#xpointer(/root/elem/*)
        |- sample3.xml#xpointer(/root/elem/*)
```

Pls note, that I am not interested in sampleX, because it is not included in sample1.xml

```
sample1.xml
<root>
    <xi:include href="sample2.xml#xpointer(/root/elem/*)" parse="xml"/>
</root>
```

```
sample2.xml
<root>
    <elem>
        <xi:include href="sample3.xml#xpointer(/root/elem/*)" parse="xml"/>
    </elem>
    <otherElem>
        <xi:include href="sampleX.xml#xpointer(/root/elem/*)" parse="xml"/>
    </otherElem>
</root>
```

```
sample3.xml
<root>
    <elem>
       <hi/>
       <ho/>
    </elem>
</root>
```

```
sampleX.xml
<root>
    <elem />
</root>
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/xinclude/#creating-result states:

> The inclusion history of each top-level included element is recorded
> in the include history extension property. The include history
> property is a list of element information representing the
> xi:include elements for recursive inclusion levels.

My questions:

1. does libxml2 adhere to the specification and store the include history?
2. via which API calls (preferably with xslt) do I get access to the include history?
3. or have I misunderstood the specification?

Any hints appreciated :-)

oerkelchen

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As this is your first question I recommend that you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. You do need to invest time to get good results from this (or any) programming forum.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with XSLT then it's a perfectly acceptable approach. I think I would do something like this:

- Use your technique to print the values of all `<xi:include>` tags in a *single* XML document
- Use a command-line FOR to process all XML documents in all directories, recursively. On Windows, `FOR` can do this easily. Or `find` on Linux.

If the dependency graph is complex, it would be fairly simple to output a [GraphViz](https://graphviz.org/) spec and render the result as a browsable graph.

Comment: This approach is not precise enough for me, because it also finds sampleX.xml, although sampleX.xml is not included in sample1.xml.

Comment: Are you trying to analyse the dependencies of a _single_ XML file, or are you trying to figure out how _all_ of the XML files are related? I was assuming the latter.

Comment: I have to analyze the dependencies of about 300 top level documents, total number of documents is about 2000, many of them probably unused...